# config.consider_all_requests_local set to true without full trace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a new app today this is my **Gemfile** :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Static pages
gem 'high_voltage', '0.9.2'

# Dry Controller
gem 'coast'

# Light Views
gem 'slim'
gem 'formtastic'

# Uploading
gem 'paperclip'

# Authentication
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'

# Easing models
gem 'enumerize'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
group :test, :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  # For slim genetaror instead default
  gem 'slim-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'forgery'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

And this an extract from my **environment/development.rb** :

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.whiny_nils = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.active_support.deprecation = :log
config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = true

Slim::Engine.set_default_options pretty: true, sort_attrs: false
```

When I go to a page with an error for example this one :

```
p
  = @project.envelopedd
```

I get a 500 page error instead of the normal debug trace. Any idea to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a "bug" in the Rails documentation. I got burned by this just now also. There is a PR open on the Rails repo to address the docs issue.

The TL;DR: is that you need to implement `show_detailed_exceptions?` instead of `local_request?`